# javascript confirm box causing idleTimeout jquery plugin to show dialog at wrong time

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, idle-timer

I've been using the idleTimeout jquery plugin from [erichynds.com](http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/a-new-and-improved-jquery-idle-timeout-plugin/) and it has been working fine in Firefox and IE...however I uncovered a weird problem when using this in chrome 11.0 .

Im using javascript "confirm" alerts to help handle the delete of items.  In Chrome, anytime the "confirm" box is called the "idleTimeout" dialog box shows up, as if the user was idle and the mouse not moving....this occurs immediately after I press one of the buttons on the confirm prompt.

I tried using the jquery ui dialog box instead of the javascript "confirm" box and the problem went away, however, I have to use a "synchronous" confirm box because of the requirements I have, so I had to scrap the jquery ui dialog box.

Any ideas how to get around this problem?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does it happen immediately even if you click on the confirm box quickly or only if you leave the confirm box open for some amount of time?  Also, have you set the idleTimeout to something very low?  By default it appears to be 10 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution at this link, down about half the way another user posted this fix for anyone else who comes across this.

[link](http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/a-new-and-improved-jquery-idle-timeout-plugin/)

---

```
No idea why Chrome alert/confirm causes idle to be triggered, but here is my work-around. In jquery.idletimer.js, the toggleSTate function, replace the the "// reset timeout counter" with:

// reset timeout counter
var elapsed = (+new Date) - f.olddate;
f.olddate = +new Date;

// handle Chrome always triggering idle after js alert or comfirm popup
if (idle && (elapsed < timeout)) {
idle = false;
clearTimeout($.idleTimer.tId);
if (enabled)
$.idleTimer.tId = setTimeout(toggleIdleState, timeout);
return;
}
```

Comment: Cheers, I have been having the same issue. Hopefully this'll take care of it.